# Problem with minimize action in gnome

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I am fond of `Ubuntu Unity` version and this is the first time when I am using gnome with the Ubuntu, and I found that minimize action is disabled by default so I enabled it by using `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock click-action 'minimize'` then I opened nautilus (file manager) then i click on **other locations** on left menu bar then two new icons (bottom two as given in image) of my two paritions came on my launcher so when I try to minimize one of the window of my partition, a new nautilus window comes instead of minimize.
I am trying to minimize the window by clicking on second bottom icon given in below image.
You can see the two extra dots shown on nautilus icons and its partion.
[image]
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I think this bug (yes I think this is the bug) isn't specific to only this version.
and can anyone tell me that why Ubuntu-gnome always comes with the **disabled window minimize action** ?
As Ubuntu has stopped delivering the **Amazon** app then Why Ubuntu is not delivering with already enabled the minimize action of window ?

Comment: On this site, you should limit to one question at one time. Some people actually prefer the behavior where clicking again does not minimize. What is the possible relation between removing the Amazon app and not implementing the minimize action?

Comment: You said `Some people actually prefer the behavior... minimize.`, I think only **1/10** people may like such functionality (I think you're not also in that list of people). and Ubuntu developers will never develop such fuctionality for only less number of poeple. (**It opposes user friendly nature of the software or OS**)

Comment: I am relating removing of the Amazon app with the minimize action because Ubuntu some where finds that amazon app is not being used by most of the users. So if Ubuntu stores the users behavior for making the decisions on what to put and what to remove in next version of Ubuntu then the **Minimize action is also one of the thing which is used by most of the users**

Comment: My mind is actually start cracking by watching on your line `Some people actually prefer the behavior where clicking again does not minimize`. and I am saying, Ubuntu does not target for **only** some people.

Comment: and bad thing is that If I click on nautilus icon instead of any bottom two icon (as shown in image) then it start minimizing.

Comment: As you changed the default behavior of the launchers, disabling the display of volumes on the launch bar may fit your case better: these launchers do not obey the dash-to-dock minimize preference, so leaving these on introduces inconsistent behavior. I did not yet see solid statistics about the percentage of users that resist the current behavior. Part of the reason may be that upstream Gnome Shell does not support click on minimize at all (they even seem to want to fase the concept out!).

Comment: That's why I love **Unity** version It allows users full control over it. Example like, we can also change the animation of minimize/un-minimize window but in Gnome their is no such options. Gnome is like a child (1 month born baby) of Unity.